# Moment.js formats locally until I specify the format

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I need to set a `datetime-local` picker's default value to the current local time. Native JS seems to output in local time by default:

```
new Date($.now()); // "Sat Nov 12 2016 22:36:52 GMT+1100 (AEDT)"
```

However functions like `toISOString()` output in UTC, and although I can pull out individual components locally, I don't really want to fiddle around with padding and such. So I try this using moment.js:

```
moment().local().format(); // "2016-11-12T22:34:05+11:00"
```

Cool! Now I just need to adjust the format to a tiny bit:

```
moment().local().format('YYYY-MM-DThh:mm'); // "2016-11-12T10:39"
```

Waaaaaaait. Now it's in UTC again, even though I specified local.

In this particular case I could use string manipulation to just drop the end off for the date-time picker, but surely I'm going to reach a point where I want to output the local time in an arbitrary format. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example isn't UTC, it's just using 12h format.

`hh` = 12h, `HH` = 24h. Try this instead:

```
moment().local().format('YYYY-MM-DTHH:mm')
```